# squid proxy basic authentication for ubuntu

Tags: basic-authentication, squid

I have set up squid proxy with Basic authentication for Ubuntu using credentials and tested with browser working fine with username and password.

Now I want to connect it through command line.  Using MacOs command lineand trying to connect to a remote terminal to a ssh port set up

```
CONNECT 192.111.222.33:22 HTTP/1.0 Proxy-Authorization: Basic <usernamepasswordencodedinbase64format> and press enter twice
```

getting this error

HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request
Server: squid/3.1.19
Mime-Version: 1.0
Date: Wed, 03 Jun 2015 13:38:35 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 3740
X-Squid-Error: ERR_INVALID_REQ 0
Vary: Accept-Language
Content-Language: en
X-Cache: MISS from localhost
X-Cache-Lookup: NONE from localhost:3128
Via: 1.0 localhost (squid/3.1.19)

```
Connection: close

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html><head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>ERROR: The requested URL could not be retrieved</title>

<ul>
<li id="missing-method"><p>Missing or unknown request method.</p></li>
<li id="missing-url"><p>Missing URL.</p></li>
<li id="missing-protocol"><p>Missing HTTP Identifier (HTTP/1.0).</p></li>
<li><p>Request is too large.</p></li>
<li><p>Content-Length missing for POST or PUT requests.</p></li>
<li><p>Illegal character in hostname; underscores are not allowed.</p></li>
<li><p>HTTP/1.1 <q>Expect:</q> feature is being asked from an HTTP/1.0 software.</p></li>
</ul>
```

Please Help

Answer (score 0):

I just need to press enter key and type this Proxy-Authorization: Basic  instead of the same line which was a mistake done because of bad information. so it will be like

```
CONNECT 192.111.222.33:22 HTTP/1.0  press enter 
Proxy-Authorization: Basic <usernamepasswordencodedinbase64format> and press enter
```